# mysql uses "." as a value separator in match(ip_list) against(string), with "," 'string' also present

Tags: java, mysql, csv, delimiter, separator

When processing ip addresses, and comparing them, something goes wrong, and it finds almost all the data from the database.
Query:

```
SELECT * FROM superbans WHERE NOT uuid=? AND (MATCH(ip_list) AGAINST(?) OR MATCH(clientId_list) AGAINST(?) OR MATCH(deviceId_list) AGAINST(?) OR MATCH(xuid_list) AGAINST(?))
```

Example uuid: `e778e3d4-7866-3601-b069-d38dd1ed2e21`

Example ip: `111.111.111.111`

Example clientId: `4848256256931583384 (but clientId maybe contains "-": -4848256256931583384)`

Example deviceId: `4a474f8b-3032-35fb-bd27-fb4e3c5435fd`

Example xuid: `2535454407347849`

If I remove MATCH(ip_list) AGAINST(?) from the query, it outputs the data correctly.
Please help me to make mysql not think that "." this is the delimiter.

IMPORTANT: in the line with "." also has ","

I tried to do it through REGEXP, because I'm just starting to learn mysql, then I didn't succeed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the . is handled as a delimiter (as are commas, spaces, and many other characters). To match the exact IP address, put double quotes around each value. Otherwise, you are going to get results matching anything with 111 (in your example IP).

Here is an example to demonstrate the results with and without the double quotes:

```
select * from country where countryname='United States';
+-------------+---------------+
| countrycode | countryname   |
+-------------+---------------+
| USA         | United States |
+-------------+---------------+

SELECT *  FROM country  WHERE  MATCH(countryname) AGAINST('United States');
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| countrycode | countryname                          |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| UMI         | United States Minor Outlying Islands |
| USA         | United States                        |
| FSM         | Micronesia, Federated States of      |
| ARE         | United Arab Emirates                 |
| GBR         | United Kingdom                       |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+

SELECT *  FROM country  WHERE  MATCH(countryname) AGAINST('United.States');
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| countrycode | countryname                          |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| UMI         | United States Minor Outlying Islands |
| USA         | United States                        |
| FSM         | Micronesia, Federated States of      |
| ARE         | United Arab Emirates                 |
| GBR         | United Kingdom                       |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+

SELECT *  FROM country  WHERE  MATCH(countryname) AGAINST('"United States"');
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| countrycode | countryname                          |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| UMI         | United States Minor Outlying Islands |
| USA         | United States                        |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+

SELECT *  FROM country  WHERE  MATCH(countryname) AGAINST('"United States","United Kingdom"');
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| countrycode | countryname                          |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
| GBR         | United Kingdom                       |
| UMI         | United States Minor Outlying Islands |
| USA         | United States                        |
+-------------+--------------------------------------+
```

But note you're not leveraging the power of fulltext search if you do this. Do you want to match partial IP addresses? If not, you could just use an IN statement like this example:

```
select * from country where countryname in ('United States', 'United Kingdom');
+-------------+----------------+
| countrycode | countryname    |
+-------------+----------------+
| GBR         | United Kingdom |
| USA         | United States  |
+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: I have 2 lists of ip, 1 which is obtained from this search (```MATCH(ip_list)```), and the second which I separate with commas (where the problem is), and I need to compare them (so that even if 1 ip matches, it displays this user) . The ip list can be greater/less than another ip list. If I do ```IN('"111.111.111.111"')``` then it doesn't display those that contain this ip (```Example ip_list: 111.111.111.111,222.222.222.222,333.333.333.333```). I immediately get this list in this form, how can I add to each ip ' " ' first and last ?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it, now it works correctly